# Adding a trendline to the following data

Tags: graphs

I am working with some data in LaTeX and was hoping to display the equation for the line as well as a trendline, most sources I have found typically deal with data obtained from an Excel file, my data has been entered manually in the LaTeX file.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Kinetic Energy vs Wavenumber},
    xlabel={Wavenumber ($\frac{1}{\lambda}$)},
    ylabel={$10^{19}$ Kinetic Energy (J)},
    xmin=2.00, xmax=4.00,
    ymin=0.00, ymax=5.00,
    xtick={0.00,2.00,2.50,3.00,3.50,4.00,4.50},
    ytick={0.00,0.50,1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00, 3.50, 4.00, 4.50},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2,0.311)(2.22,0.700)(2.50,1.34)(2.86,1.89)(3.33,3.09)(4.00,4.49)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This generates the following graph:

[image: Graph Generated by data]

Comment: Welcome! It would be much easier if you plotted the table, then the `linear regression` could be used to produce this "trend line".

Answer (score 2):

If you deal with tables, you may just plot the table instead of converting the data manually to coordinates. Then it is very easy to add a regression line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Kinetic Energy vs Wavenumber},
    xlabel={Wavenumber ($\frac{1}{\lambda}$)},
    ylabel={$10^{19}$ Kinetic Energy (J)},
    xmin=2.00, xmax=4.00,
    ymin=0.00, ymax=5.00,
    xtick={0.00,2.00,2.50,3.00,3.50,4.00,4.50},
    ytick={0.00,0.50,1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00, 3.50, 4.00, 4.50},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    table[col sep=comma] {
    lambda,Ekin
    2,0.311
    2.22,0.700
    2.50,1.34
    2.86,1.89
    3.33,3.09
    4.00,4.49
    };
\addplot[
    color=red,
    ]
    table[col sep=comma,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Ekin}}] {
    lambda,Ekin
    2,0.311
    2.22,0.700
    2.50,1.34
    2.86,1.89
    3.33,3.09
    4.00,4.49
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can just load the table in a macro,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
    lambda,Ekin
    2,0.311
    2.22,0.700
    2.50,1.34
    2.86,1.89
    3.33,3.09
    4.00,4.49
}{\mytable}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Kinetic Energy vs Wavenumber},
    xlabel={Wavenumber ($\frac{1}{\lambda}$)},
    ylabel={$10^{19}$ Kinetic Energy (J)},
    xmin=2.00, xmax=4.00,
    ymin=0.00, ymax=5.00,
    xtick={0.00,2.00,2.50,3.00,3.50,4.00,4.50},
    ytick={0.00,0.50,1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00, 3.50, 4.00, 4.50},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    table  \mytable;
\addplot[
    color=red,
    ]
    table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Ekin}}] \mytable
    node[pos=0.5,sloped,above]{$E_\mathrm{kin}\simeq
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona}\cdot10^{19}\,\mathrm{J}/\lambda$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or plot the data directly from a file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Is there any way you could share how you might go about adding an equation to the line, or is that something I would have to import from an Excel file?

Comment: @djohnson I added an equation, in which I use the slope that `pgfplots` computes and stores in `\pgfplotstableregressiona`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!